# How to hide flashing dialog content when page is loading?

Tags: tailwind-css, alpine.js

On tailwindcss, Alpinejs page I use modal which is opened by click on button.
Problem is that while page is loading I see flashing dialog content.
I tried to set hidden class to modal window and in the end of init method
to set isPageLoaded variable into true

```
<div class="overflow-auto border-2 border-grey-900" x-data="app()" x-init="appInit()">

    <div class="w-full h-full">
        <button
            type="button"
            class="bg-transparent border border-gray-500 hover:border-indigo-500 text-gray-500 hover:text-indigo-500 font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded-full"
            @click="showModal = true"
        >Open modal
        </button>
    </div>
    <!--Overlay-->

    <div class="overflow-auto w-full h-full hidden" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)" x-show="showModal" :class="{ 'fixed inset-0 z-10 flex items-center justify-center': showModal, 'visible' : isPageLoaded }">

...
<script>

    function app() {
        return {
            showModal : false,
            isPageLoaded : false,

            appInit: function () {
                console.log('appInit::')
                this.isPageLoaded= true
            },

        }
    }

</script>
```

As a result I do not see flashing dialog content, but I can not show  dialog modal, which I tried to set with:

```
'visible' : isPageLoaded
```

I mean to toggle hidden class I set by default. But that does not work.

Could you please check pen :
https://codepen.io/petrogromovo/pen/yLMNVLr

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `x-cloak` to hide elements from display until Alpine has fully loaded. https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine#x-cloak

Add the `x-cloak` attribute to any element that you want to hide, and add this rule to your stylesheet.

```
[x-cloak] { display: none; }
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like it works.
Also have I always to put  x-cloak in the same div with x-data and x-init ?
I suppose in all cases I have to hide html inside x-data and x-init ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo You can put it on any element. In this specific case, you should put it on the element that has `x-show="showModal"`, since that's the element you don't want flashing up while the page is loading.

Comment: Why do they not fix it, so you do not need x-cloak on everything?